# Unable to call web url from Dynamics 365 plugin (error)

Tags: plugins, microsoft-dynamics

We have a Dynamics 365 instance for which we are writing plugins.  We are having trouble calling an Azure function, I suspect because I need to allow the Dynamics IP address through.  So we wrote code to call a http web site that would return the IP address.  This also throws an error.  It seems any attempt to make a HTTP call inside the plugin creates an error.  Every guide I read online says we can use HTTP and HTTPS if we have a URL, but it's just not working.  We've tried a couple of different classes for HTTP calls.  For my function I have copied the code out and it works.  When it throws in the plugin the error is not that the IP is not valid (that's what I got before adding my IP locally), so I feel sure something is blocking HTTP calls before they are made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your WebURL contains an IP address or a DNS. If it does not contain a DNS would suggest to have a WebURL with DNS.
But below are the limitations with Plug-in in Sandbox mode:

- No mechanism for ‘shared’ or ‘helper’ assemblies – must use ILMerge
- Execute with partial trust
- 2-minute timeout
- Only HTTP/HTTPS protocols allowed
- Cannot access network via IP (only DNS)
- Resource usage/management: since plugins run inside the CRM resource
  pool, pushing resource-intensive tasks outside of CRM reduces overall
  load on the system

Also, you can go through the below link to see another way to consume Azure functions as Web hooks in D365 plugins.

https://www.akaes.com/blog/writing-microsoft-dynamics-365-plug-ins-in-azure-functions/

Comment: Fair response, I should have said.  I knew about this limitation.  It's a URL, not an IP address.  I've read all this googling my issue and I don't think we are falling foul of any of this.  The error is happening when literally all the code does is hit a GET (http, not https) to get back the IP address I need to open up to use my Azure function.

Comment: As the only output we can get is exception text, I am doing this.  This is the whole function and it gives an error 

  HttpClient c = new HttpClient();

            var resp = c.GetAsync("http://checkip.dyndns.com/").Result;


            var ip = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            throw new Exception(ip);

I am working with a friend, I am the C# guy and he is Dynamics.  I am not telling you the error because I don't know but I feel sure it indicated something to do with permission to make a HTTP call.

Comment: Thanks for providing more information. I tried the code you have mentioned above and it worked fine for me in a plugin. I was able to retrieve the IP and save it in an attribute on D365 entity. I am sure you must have mentioned the protocol i.e HTTP in the URL you are using because it was the only change that I had to do, as I can see that it removes the protocol from the comments.

Comment: I hadn't spotted we'd not made that explicit, trying that now :)

Comment: OK, needing HTTP in the URL was the solution to our issue making calls, so thanks :)

Comment: Great...I am glad that I was able to help:)